# Adding Lat Lon coordinates to separate columns (python/dataframe)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm sure this is a simple thing to do but I am new to Python and cannot work it out!

I have a data frame with one column containing coordinates and I am wanting to remove the brackets and add the Lat/Lon values into separate columns.

Current dataframe:

```
gridReference
(56.37769816725615, -4.325049868061924) 
(56.37769816725615, -4.325049868061924) 
(51.749167440074324, -4.963575226888083)
```

wanted dataframe:

```
Latitude               Longitude
56.37769816725615     -4.325049868061924
56.37769816725615     -4.325049868061924
51.749167440074324    -4.963575226888083
```

Thanks for your help

EDIT:
I have tried:

`df['lat'], df['lon'] = df.gridReference.str.strip(')').str.strip('(').str.split(', ').values.tolist()`

but I get the error:

`AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object_ dtype in pandas`

I then tried adding:

`df['gridReference'] = df['gridReference'].astype('str')`

and got the error:

`ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)`

Any help would be appreciated as I am not sure how to make this work! :)

**EDIT:**
I keep getting the error 
`AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object_ dtype in pandas`

the output for df.dtypes is:

`<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 22899 entries, 0 to 22898
Data columns (total 1 columns):
LatLon    22899 non-null object
dtypes: object(1)`

the output for df.info() is:

`gridReference  object
dtype: object`

Comment: Please provide a sample of your data along with your tried attempts.

Comment: I have added some information. If you could help in any way it would be appreciated!

Answer (score 8):

```
df['gridReference'].str.strip('()')                               \
                   .str.split(', ', expand=True)                   \
                   .rename(columns={0:'Latitude', 1:'Longitude'}) 

             Latitude           Longitude
0   56.37769816725615  -4.325049868061924
1   56.37769816725615  -4.325049868061924
2  51.749167440074324  -4.963575226888083
```

Comment: Nice - but i think you can add strip whitespace in second column and cast output to `float` (I think better is float as string looks like float)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I think `astype(float)` doesn't account for the entire decimal place(gives a precision upto 6 places, although you could change it by setting it at the beginning). I have left it to OP to consider how he wants to go forward from here.

Comment: Ok, no problem.

Comment: Ya, it is another solution.

Comment: I keep getting the error `Can only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object_ dtype in pandas` regardless of what I do. What do I need to add to get this to work? Thanks for your help

Comment: @hsquared, Does adding `df['gridReference'].astype(str)` help? If it does not, could you do `df.info()` and `df.dtypes` and place their outputs along with the question?

Comment: It didn't help; it appears that it is an `object` - so I need to convert object to string? I posted the .dtype and info() above.

Comment: And also `type(df['gridReference'].iloc[0])`?

Answer (score 2):

Answering to the question:
Input is a column with tuples similar column b in my code.
Output needed is two columns which is similar to b1 and b2 column in my answer.

Created a DataFrame:
    In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2], 'b':[(1,2), (3,4)]})

```
In [3]: df                                                                                                                                                                      
Out[3]: 
   a       b
0  1  (1, 2)
1  2  (3, 4)
```

Convert a column to list:

```
In [4]: df['b'].tolist()                                                                                                                                                        
Out[4]: [(1, 2), (3, 4)]
```

Create required dataframe [Output required]  using the list:

```
In [5]: pd.DataFrame(df['b'].tolist(), index=df.index)                                                                                                                                          
Out[5]: 
   0  1
0  1  2
1  3  4
```

We can also try to get the output in the same dataframe using the below code:
    In [6]: df[['b1', 'b2']] = pd.DataFrame(df['b'].tolist(), index=df.index)

```
In [7]: df                                                                                                                                                                      
Out[7]: 
   a       b  b1  b2
0  1  (1, 2)   1   2
1  2  (3, 4)   3   4
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Sure @SurajRao I will update and edit the answer as per your advise

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'latlong': ['(12, 32)', '(43, 54)']})
>>> df
    latlong
0  (12, 32)
1  (43, 54)

>>> split_data = df.latlong.str.strip(')').str.strip('(').str.split(', ')
>>> df['lat'] = split_data.apply(lambda x: x[0])
>>> df['long'] = split_data.apply(lambda x: x[1])
    latlong lat long
0  (12, 32)  12   43
1  (43, 54)  32   54
```

Comment: I get the error: "AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object_ dtype in pandas" - what would I have to do before for it to work? - Thanks.

Comment: doing `df.dtypes` shows:
`gridReference    object
dtype: object`

Comment: Edited the answer. Also do check for any NA's in your data

Comment: Thanks for your help but it still gives the same error - I don't think there are any NAs