# How to separate a column of a pandas dataframe that contains the geographic coordinates in two columns for latitudes and longitudes?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following pandas dataframe:

```
      import pandas as pd

      df = pd.DataFrame({'NAME': ['Paris', 'New York', 'Rio'],
                         'GEO': ['POINT (48.85 2.31647)',
                                 'POINT (40.731499671618 -73.993457389558)',
                                 'POINT (-22.9 -43.2)']})

      print(df)

       NAME            GEO
       Paris      POINT (48.85 2.31647)
       New York   POINT (40.731499671618 -73.993457389558)
       Rio        POINT (-22.9 -43.2)
```

I need to separate the GEO column into two columns. One column to store latitude and another column to store longitude.

So, based on this code: [Adding Lat Lon coordinates to separate columns (python/dataframe)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39396678/adding-lat-lon-coordinates-to-separate-columns-python-dataframe) , I implemented the following:

```
       df['GEO'].str('POINT ()').str.strip(' ', expand=True).rename(columns={0:'LAT', 1:'LONG'})
```

However, it is giving the error: "TypeError: 'StringMethods' object is not callable"

I would like the output to be:

```
      NAME             GEO                                   LAT              LONG
       Paris      POINT (48.85 2.31647)                      48.85            2.31647
       New York   POINT (40.731499671618 -73.993457389558)   40.731499671618  -73.993457389558
       Rio        POINT (-22.9 -43.2)                        -22.9            -43.2
```

Comment: .str is not callable. The .str('POINT ()') is where the error is being thrown. You will need to convert that string a different way

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regex:

```
df2 = df.join(df['GEO'].str.extract(r'(?P<LAT>-?\d+\.\d+) (?P<LONG>-?\d+\.\d+)'))
```

output:

```
       NAME                                       GEO              LAT              LONG
0     Paris                     POINT (48.85 2.31647)            48.85           2.31647
1  New York  POINT (40.731499671618 -73.993457389558)  40.731499671618  -73.993457389558
2       Rio                       POINT (-22.9 -43.2)            -22.9             -43.2
```

or, to get `float`:

```
df2 = df.join(df['GEO'].str.extract(r'(?P<LAT>-?\d+\.\d+) (?P<LONG>-?\d+\.\d+)'))
              .astype(float))
```

output:

```
       NAME                                       GEO      LAT       LONG
0     Paris                     POINT (48.85 2.31647)  48.8500   2.316470
1  New York  POINT (40.731499671618 -73.993457389558)  40.7315 -73.993457
2       Rio                       POINT (-22.9 -43.2) -22.9000 -43.200000
```

Comment: oof, regex...now you have two problems

Comment: @Jhirschibar this is a myth ;) regexes are awesome

Answer (score 0):

You were very close. But the `.str` function is not callable. You can not invoke it as [`.str()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.html#pandas.Series.str). Modify your code to this and it works (but won't be quite as sleek as your one-liner)

```
df[['POINT', 'LAT', 'LONG']]  = df['GEO'].str.split(' ', expand=True).rename(columns=({0:'POINT', 1:'LAT', 2:'LONG'}))

df['LAT'] = df['LAT'].str.replace('(','')
df['LONG'] = df['LONG'].str.replace(')','')
```

You can then delete `df['POINT']`